# Shift+Right Click to Open .pptx as Read-Only?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-powerpoint, regedit

When I use shift+right click to open a file as read-only, Office opens the document in standard mode instead. I made registry changes based on the second-to-last post in this thread ([How can I open a file as read-only from Windows Explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/48460/how-can-i-open-a-file-as-read-only-from-windows-explorer)) which fixed my issues for Word and Excel, but I don't know how to make the same changes for PowerPoint. Does anyone know the specific Registry Keys to add/change to fix this issue?

I'm running Office 2010 on Windows 7 on my work machine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Would RightClick->Properties->Check the box 'Read Only' Then opening the file work for you?

I would think this would be a safer option than editing registry keys.

Comment: It works, but it's a little cumbersome. I open a lot of shared documents, so I'd have to set them as read-only, open, then set them back to normal every time. Ideally, I'd like to make a few registry tweaks once and not have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you open Registry editor (regedit) you should be able to find a key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Powerpoint.Show.12\shell
```

Add a new key under that:

```
OpenAsReadOnly
```

Add a String value:

```
(Default)
```

with value

```
Open as Read-Only
```

and another String as:

```
Extended
```

with empty value.
Add another key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PowerPoint.Show.12\shell\OpenAsReadOnly:

```
command
```

Add a string:

```
(Default)
```

with value:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\POWERPNT.EXE" /h %1
```

The path to powerpnt.exe might differ for your version of Office. (It's 12 for Office 2007, 14 for Office 2010 and 15 for Office 2015.)

After that you should be able to shift+right click on a pptx file and select open as read-only.
Repeat the process with

```
 HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PowerPoint.Show.8\shell
```

if you'd like the same behaviour for .ppt files.

**Disclaimer**:
You should make a backup, and proceed with caution...blah-blah-blah.

One more option if you don't want or don't have the necessary privileges to modify a registry key: Open PowerPoint, then when you select the ppt/pptx file to open, click on the little arrow on the button "Open" and there should be an option to open the file as read-only. I know this doesn't answer your question, as it's not the shift+right click menu, but wanted to include it for others who may be more comfortable with this option.