# Is there a way to record macros to do things I would normally do in Windows explorer? E.g. Open an Excel file read-only?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, windows-explorer, macros

Countless times a day, I go into Windows Explorer, shift-right click on an Excel file, Copy as path, then go into Run, type `Excel /r` (paste), which opens my Excel file as read only.

Is there a way to record all this (and similar routine tasks) in a macro, so that I could easily open these files this way? E.g. Shift-Enter opens the file as an Excel read only, as in the mechanism above?

Loosely related to [How can I open a file as read-only from Windows Explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/48460/how-can-i-open-a-file-as-read-only-from-windows-explorer)

Answer (score 4):

[Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is definitely the way to go here.

As long as you're Shift-rightclicking, though, why not just Open as Read-Only? 
[image]

**edit**: as mentioned below, it doesn't work (?!?).

Back to my original suggestion. Autohotkey can record you doing this with the ScriptWriter module, which you can then tweak.
You'll probably end up with something like:

`IfWinActive, ahk_class XLMAIN
^B:: ; hotkey is CTRL + B but can be changed to anything
ExcelFileName := "C:\path\to\file.xlsx" ; this needs to be replaced with a variable
Send, {LWINDOWN}r{LWINUP} ;opens Run
WinWaitActive, Run, 
Send, excel{SPACE}/r{SPACE}ExcelFileName{Enter}`

If you tell me more about how your files are stored (any naming conventions? etc) I can help you get the path into the hotkey. Without that all I can come up with is a nasty VBA -> AHK kludge from within the Excel file you want, like

`Sub GetPath()
Dim CompletePath As String
CompletePath = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
MsgBox CompletePath
End Sub`

which you could then dump into the AHK script as `ExcelFileName`.

**edit 2:**
I think with the desired Excel file highlighted `Send {Ctrl Down}c{Ctrl Up}` will copy the file *path* into the Clipboard, which you could then pass in as `ExcelFileName := %clipboard%`.

Try this. Highlight your file and hit CTRL + B.

`^B:: ; hotkey is CTRL + B but can be changed to anything
Send {Ctrl Down}c{Ctrl Up} ; copies path to Clipboard (unverified)
ExcelFileName := %clipboard% ; plaintext
Send, {LWINDOWN}r{LWINUP} ; opens Run
WinWaitActive, Run, 
Send, excel{SPACE}/r{SPACE}ExcelFileName{Enter}`

Comment: Because that option doesn't work and hasn't been fixed. (Try it out.)

Comment: Thanks this is a great start! I really want to be able to open any Excel file as read only, and would need the script to recognize what file I've selected in Windows Explorer (is highlighted blue) and what folder it's in.

Comment: I'm going to try edit 1 before edit 2, just because I'd rather not lose something I may have copied before opening the excel file.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "which you could then dump into the AHK script as ExcelFileName"?

Comment: That was an attempt to get the path of the file via VBA. If you want to test that first one, just hardcode the path in.

Comment: ExcelFileName := %clipboard% ; plaintext is giving me an error message so far (though I'm quite new to ahk). I'm checking this out now: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/60985-get-paths-of-selected-items-in-an-explorer-window/

Comment: This worked for me: "Send, excel{SPACE}/r{SPACE}%clipboard%{Enter}"!!!

Comment: Excellent, that is cleaner anyway.

Comment: One more tweak: The macro as is doesn't handle filenames/folders with spaces. This I believe is better: Send, excel{SPACE}/r{SPACE}"%clipboard%"{Enter}