# "Open as Read-Only" but workbook still opens as writeable

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

When I press `Shift+Right-click` when clicking on a workbook's filename, I get the "Open as Read-Only" option in the context menu, but when I click this option and the workbook opens, it's in read/write mode, and I'm able to save changes.

How can I actually open the workbook in Read-Only?

Comment: Seems like "Open in protected view" is what you want - http://superuser.com/questions/48460/how-can-i-open-a-file-as-read-only-from-windows-explorer#comment961249_472429

Comment: @MichaelFrank, no, that won't let me edit.  I want to be able to make changes to the document, but only be able to save them under a different filename.

Comment: That makes sense. Perhaps take a look at the rest of the answers on that page.

Comment: @MichaelFrank, I made the registry changes suggested in [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/655841/93980) but workbooks still open in read/write.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to open an Excel File as "Read Only", try this..

Open Excel. Then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, to open the Open File dialog box.

Then try this to open the file as read only:

[image]

Comment: I'm ideally trying to open files in read-only from Windows Explorer.  Basically I want to make the "Open as Read-Only" in the context menu do what it's supposed to do.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Your question does not specify 'Windows Explorer' only mode. Btw, what OS and Excel version are you using?

Comment: Seems to be a known bug http://www.consumingexperience.com/2014/02/open-word-or-excel-document-read-only.html

Comment: Win7 and Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say a user that you can just run this, so ....

I think your answer at last is using two `batch` files :

Read-only batch file codes:

```
@echo off
attrib <file.xlsx> +a +r
file.xlsx
```

Normal batch file codes :

```
@echo off
attrib <file.xlsx> -a -r
file.xlsx
```

I know that; this can be just the last way ...

Answer (score -1):

In case you want to open a word (in read only) because another one will use this later so you can do as following:

Open word, then exploring to the word you want to open read-only, choose option read-only option in below, so you can read-only the file.